# JSONB sqlalchemy Aggregate Function

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

With SQLAlchemy I want to reproduce the available [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) jsonb_object_agg from a subquery `sq_objects`:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func
s = select([
    sq_objects.c.object_id,
    func.jsonb_object_agg(
        sq_objects.c.keys, sq_objects.c.values).over(
        partition_by=sq_objects.c.object_id).label("attributes"),
]).\
    distinct(sq_objects.c.object_id)
```

However, the execute returns:

> (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'method'

```
[ SQL: "SELECT DISTINCT ON (sq_objects.object_id)
     sq_objects.object_id,
     jsonb_object_agg(
         %(jsonb_object_agg_1)s,
         %(jsonb_object_agg_2)s
     ) OVER (PARTITION BY sq_objects.object_id) AS attributes
 FROM (SELECT ... ) AS sq_objects"
] [
parameters: {'jsonb_object_agg_1': <bound method Properties.keys of <sqlalchemy.sql.base.ImmutableColumnCollection object at 0x7f0ffb7aa828>>,
             'jsonb_object_agg_2': <bound method Properties.values of <sqlalchemy.sql.base.ImmutableColumnCollection object at 0x7f0ffb7aa828>>}]
```

This is the sql code I want to reproduce:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (sq_objects.object_id)
    sq_objects.object_id,
    jsonb_object_agg(
        sq_objects.keys,
        sq_objects.values
    ) OVER (PARTITION BY sq_objects.object_id) AS attributes
FROM (SELECT ... ) AS sq_objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the attributes `keys` and `values` are methods of the immutable column collection `sq_objects.c`. Another solution to the problem is to use item access notation for getting the actual columns:

```
func.jsonb_object_agg(
    sq_objects.c["keys"],
    sq_objects.c["values"]
).over(
    partition_by=sq_objects.c.object_id
).label("attributes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant implementation, but since I now the labels of the subquery columns; a raw `text` input solves the issue:

```
func.jsonb_object_agg(
    text("sq_objects.keys"),
    text("sq_objects.values")
).over(
    partition_by=sq_objects.c.object_id).label("attributes"),
```