# SQLAlchemy classical mapper custom data type, dict from columns

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'd like to use the classical mapper to map a class that uses dicts as its internal data structure, to some regular relational tables:

```
# my class
class Order:

    def __init__(self, id: str, lines: dict):
        self.lines = lines  

# order lines are a mapping of product code to quantity ordered,
# eg: Order(id='order-id', lines={'product1': 23, 'product2', 12})


# my tables
order = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'order', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
)

order_lines = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'order_lines', metadata,
    Column('order_id', ForeignKey('order.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('product_code', String(255), primary_key=True),
    Column('quantity', Integer),
)
```

now, how to configure `mapper` in such a way that it will do the join to the order_lines table, and then transform the order_lines into dicts mapping the product_code column to the quantity column?

[edit]: maybe something like `attribute_based_collection` could work? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#proxying-to-dictionary-based-collections

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801904/jsonb-sqlalchemy-aggregate-function.