# How do you write MySQL query using JSON_OBJECTAGG on SQLAlchemy's SQL Expression Language?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-8.0

I'm using SQLAlchemy on MySQL 8.0.
I'm trying to compose a query which uses [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) function on the SQL Expression Language.
Since it is predefined function in MySQL, I'm wondering if there is canonical way for achieving this purpose.

#### Question

- What is the recommended way to compose a query using [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) function on SQL Expression Language?

Comment: Here's an answer for PostGreSQL, maybe it also works for MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43801904/jsonb-sqlalchemy-aggregate-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no restrictions<sup>1</sup> to what SQL functions can be called using [`func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html). Given the example from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg):

> ```
> mysql> SELECT o_id, attribute, value FROM t3;
> ```

```
+------+-----------+--------+
| o_id | attribute | value  |
+------+-----------+--------+
|    2 | color     | red    |
|    2 | fabric    | silk   |
|    3 | color     | green  |
|    3 | shape     | square |
+------+-----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the query:

> ```
> SELECT o_id, JSON_OBJECTAGG(attribute, value)
> ```

```
   FROM t3 GROUP BY o_id;
```

would be expressed in SQLAlchemy [SQL Expression Language](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) as:

```
select([t3.c.o_id, func.json_objectagg(t3.c.attribute, t3.c.value)]).\
    group_by(t3.c.o_id)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In practice there are some restrictions. `func` cannot be used to generate function calls using named notation easily, for example.

Comment: what is t3 in this? It's undefined. Is it a table, or an object, or another select?

Comment: `t3` is the table that's used in the MySQL documentation in the example queries. Building the equivalent SQLA `Table` is omitted in this example, as it is trivial.